# SQLAlchemy: if you are with me, I'm with you - self referential M2M relationships again

Tags: many-to-many, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a social-network like many-to-many mapping in SQLAlchemy. That is I have a Character class and a character_relations cross table to link from Character to Character. Until now this is easy:

```
character_relationships = Table('character_relationships', Base.metadata,
    Column('me_id', Integer, ForeignKey('characters.id', ondelete=True, onupdate=True), nullable=False, primary_key=True),
    Column('other_id', Integer, ForeignKey('characters.id', ondelete=True, onupdate=True), nullable=False, primary_key=True),
    UniqueConstraint('me_id', 'other_id', name='uix_1')
)

class CharacterRelationship(object):

    def __init__(self, me_id, other_id):
        self.me_id = me_id
        self.other_id = other_id

mapper(CharacterRelationship, character_relationships)

class Character(IdMixin, TimestampMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = "characters"

    name = Column(Unicode, nullable=False)

    friends = relationship(lambda: Character, secondary=character_relationships, 
             primaryjoin=lambda: Character.id==character_relationships.c.me_id,
             secondaryjoin=lambda: Character.id==character_relationships.c.other_id,
             backref=backref('knows_me')
             )
```

There are two possible relationships: unilateral and bilateral. That is in the cross table I can have

```
CharacterRelationship(me_id=1, other_id=2)
CharacterRelationship(me_id=2, other_id=1)
```

The Character.friends argument as given above is about unilater relationships. How can one add a property/column_property for bilateral relationships?

That is my_character.real_friends contains only entries from CharacterRelationship if the relationship "stands from both sides".

I know that I could use something like

```
@property
def real_friends(self):
    return set(my_character.friends) & set(my_character.knows_me)
```

but this doesn't translate well to sql, and I would expect a huge speedup doing this set intersection at the database level. But there is even more to achieve!

Even better would be to have a final object like:

```
character.friends.other_character
character.friends.relationship_type = -1 | 0 | 1
```

where

- -1 means I know other unilaterally,
- 0 bilateral,
- 1 means other knows me unilaterally

Do you see any reason to put this logic at the database level? If yes, how would you do it?
If know, do you know how to put the simple real_friend bilateral part at the database level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For real_friends, you would want to query this at the database level. It should look something like this:

```
@property
def real_friends(self):
    char_rels1 = aliased(CharacterRelationship)
    char_rels2 = aliased(CharacterRelationship)
    return DBSession.query(Character).\
        join(char_rels1, char_rels1.other_id == Character.id).\
        filter(char_rels1.me_id == self.id).\
        join(char_rels2, char_rels2.me_id == Character.id).\
        filter(char_rels2.other_id == self.id).all()
```

You can of course set this as a relationship.

For other_character (I'm assuming these are non-mutual friends), I would do a similar query but with an outerjoin.

For relationship_type, I would do the following while caching knows_person():

```
def knows_person(self, person):
    return bool(DBSession.query(CharacterRelationship).\
        filter(CharacterRelationship.me_id == self.id).\
        filter(CharacterRelationship.other_id == person.id).\
        first())

def rel_type(self, person):
    knows = self.knows_person(person)
    known = person.knows_person(self)
    if knows and known:
        return 0
    elif knows:
        return -1
    elif known:
        return 1
    return None
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `object_session(self)`

Answer (score 2):

Having your relationship `friends` defined, `real_friends` is easily done as following:

```
@property
def real_friends(self):
    qry = (Session.object_session(self).query(User).
            join(User.friends, aliased=True).filter(User.id == self.id).
            join(User.knows_me, aliased=True).filter(User.id == self.id)
          )
    return qry.all()
```

, but this will make two more redundant `JOIN`s to `User` table, so although IMO, it is a better code, it might be inferior to the version of Jonathan where simple `JOIN`s to the `CharacterRelationship` table are used.

As for the **even better** option you ask for: this can again be done in a query like below (taken @Jonathan's answer as reference):

```
@property
def all_friends(self):
    char_rels1 = aliased(Friendship)
    char_rels2 = aliased(Friendship)
    qry = (Session.object_session(self).query(User, case([(char_rels1.id <> None, 1)], else_=0)+case([(char_rels2.id <> None, 2)], else_=0)).
        outerjoin(char_rels1, and_(char_rels1.friends == User.id, char_rels1.knows_me == self.id)).
        outerjoin(char_rels2, and_(char_rels2.knows_me == User.id, char_rels2.friends == self.id)).
        filter(or_(char_rels1.id <> None, char_rels2.id <> None)) # @note: exclude those that are not connected at all
        )
    return qry.all()
```

Few things to note:

- the `filter` is moved to the `join` condition - this is very important for outer joins, or else the result would be wrong.
- the result would be `[(User, _code_), ..]`, where `_code_` is: 0 - no connected, 1 - friend, 2 - knows me, 3 - real friend (both ways)